# Sketch: different pages saved as different files?

Tags: website-design, sketch-app, interface-design

When designing web pages in Sketch... what is the standard way to deal with different pages?

So say if I design a homepage in one file, do I create a new file for, say, an 'about' page? Or would a designer typically have all pages saved in one file but across different artboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely keep them in the same file so I can reuse elements, styles, and symbols.

Then, I usually have one web/app page per sketch page, and artboards for different states/views/device sizes, for example

```
myproject.sketch
 ↳ Login (page)
   ↳ Desktop version (artboard)
   ↳ Mobile version (artboard)
 ↳ Dashboard (page)
   ↳ Desktop version (artboard)
   ↳ Mobile version (artboard)
```

Comment: I didn't realise there was such as thing as different sketch pages... thanks! :)

Answer (score -3):

works in the same file all but divides each section by folder, this will help to maintain the same diagram and the programmer can extract faster each section when you pass the file psd

Comment: the question is about Sketch, so nothing to do with PSDs